# Pass some parameters between pages in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I try to port some Windows Phone 8 projects to current UWP, and get stucked in this snippet code that I've used in old project.

```
private void Restaurant_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    string types = "restaurant";
    string title = "restaurant";
    string url = string.Format("/NearbyPlaces.xaml?latitude={0}&longitude={1}&types={2}&title={3}", LocationLatitude.Text, LocationLangitude.Text, types, title);
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

In that code, I used NavigationService to pass some parameters to another page. I couldn't use NaigationService anymore because UWP doesn't support it. I've tried using this in my UWP project, but I think it only supported for passing one parameter, CMIIW.

```
private void restaurant_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string types = "restaurant";
    string title = "restaurant";
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(placeResult), latLoc.Text, longLoc.Text, types, title);
}
```

That code give me an error, because it takes 5 arguments, which is +2 overloads. My question is how to do in proper way to passing some parameters in UWP project?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

What you passed in Windows (Phone) 8 has just been a simple `string` that included all your parameters. You had to parse them in the `OnNavigatedTo()` method of your target page. Of course you can still do that and pass a string to the `Frame.Navigate()` method.

But since UWP you can pass complete objects to other pages. So why don't you create a small class that includes all your parameters and pass an instance of that?

Your class could look like:

```
public class RestaurantParams
{
    public RestaurantParams(){}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And then pass it via:

```
var parameters = new RestaurantParams();
parameters.Name = "Lorem ipsum";
parameters.Text = "Dolor sit amet.";
// ...

Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageTwo), parameters);
```

On your next page you can now access them via:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var parameters = (RestaurantParams)e.Parameter;

    // parameters.Name
    // parameters.Text
    // ...
}
```

Where Parameter is the function that retrieves the arguments.

Comment: I tried the above in UWP projects this gives me an error   Your parameter must be serializable. If it isn't, then use SessionState. Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: That means, the the parameters you pass can't be converted to a string in the background. Can you show us the parameters you pass?

Comment: I cut and pasted this exact class (RestaurantParams) into my project to test and I get the same error. I'm thinking maybe UWP has changed this somehow. I know on an earlier project I sent strings through successfully but not for this one.

Comment: The sample I provided is for UWP and works for me. Can you give us more detailed information about the exception and your project?

Comment: I've updated the sample. FYI serializeable class needs a parameterless constructor. e.g public RestaurantParams(){},  on a new line type ctor<tab><tab>