# Passing parameters between UWP pages

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm working on a simple app based on the [XAMLNavigation sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlNavigation). I have modified the [AppShell.xaml](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlNavigation/shared/AppShell.xaml) file so that a click on the setting button will navigate the user to a SettingPage.

```
<Button x:Name="SettingsNavPaneButton"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Style="{StaticResource SplitViewPaneButtonStyle}"
                        Content="&#xE713;"
                        Click="SettingsNavPaneButton_Clicked"
                        AutomationProperties.Name="Settings"
                        ToolTipService.ToolTip="Settings"/>
```

The following is the content of the SettingPage:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SettlerBalancer.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Height="200" Width="Auto" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="24,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CheckBox x:Name="tileBalance" Grid.Row="0" Content="Text Tile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-28.8" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Click="tileBalance_Click"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="portBalance" Grid.Row="1" Content="Text port" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-28.8" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Click="portBalance_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

In this page, I have 2 checkboxes which are the parameters I want to pass to the [BasicPage](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlNavigation/cs/Views/BasicPage.xaml.cs) or [LandingPage](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlNavigation/cs/Views/LandingPage.xaml.cs).

From my understanding, you can pass parameters between pages by overriding the OnNavigation method as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304615/pass-some-parameters-between-pages-in-uwp). This means in SettingPage.xaml.cs, I must pass the parameters like this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage), parameters);
Frame.Navigate(typeof(LandingPage), parameters);
```

However, in my case, the BasicPage and LandingPage are not actually pages but frames in a split-view panel and they can only be accessed through a [NavigationListView](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlNavigation/cs/Controls/NavMenuListView.cs). Although the SettingPage is part of the splitview, it is not part of the NavigationListView. Therefore, from the SettingPage, I do not know which page (BasicPage or LandingPage) the user is going to go to as they use the NavigationListView to navigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings class to save/restore the settings. You have not to create your own settings class. 
Following url may helps you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data

And,

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage), parameters);
```

Basically, the parameter of navigation methods is suitable for the 'navigation' purpose - like as browsing url, etc. 
Because, the navigation methods have feature of save/restore navigation stack. It's useless to save/restore the application settings value. It's not related to 'Navigation' :)

Comment: That makes sense. You are right that these parameters that I want to pass are application settings value.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep it simple and create a static application settings class

```
public static ApplicationSettings{
     private static Dictionary<string,object> _settingsCache = 
                                          new Dictionary<string,object>();

     public static void AddItem(string itemKey, object itemValue){
                _settingsCache.add(itemKey,itemValue);
     }

     public static object GetItem(string itemKey){
               _settingsCache[itemKey];
     }
}
```

Comment: This cache, is it the same as a global variable?

Comment: @v4r yeah essentially. What I do is I have a ApplicationServices class that contains logic for things like this, handling exceptions, writing to storage etc.

Answer (score -1):

Pass parameter to other page by following way..

```
private void myclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
   show s = new show() { name = name.Text, desig = desig.Text, sal = int.Parse(sal.Text) };
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), s);
}
```

Below code to get value of parameter to targeted form

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)    
{
   show s =(show) e.Parameter;
   name.Text = "Your Name is: "+ s.name;
   desig.Text = "your Designation is: "+ s.desig;
   sal.Text = "Your Salary is: "+ s.sal.ToString();
}
```