# UWP passing data between pages

Tags: uwp

this is probably trivial but I couldn't find the answer.

Basically, I have a page1 (which is actually a UserControl) that has a textbox and a button next to it, after clicking the button I need to open a new standalone page with a grid, select a value and return it as a simple string or int back to page1.

I know that OnNavigatedTo could be used somehow in this scenario, but what should I do if I had more textbox+button (same as previous - select from another page) on the page1 and how can I navigate to the specific UserControl

What is the best solution to this?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304615/pass-some-parameters-between-pages-in-uwp

Answer (score 0):

> but what should I do if I had more textbox+button (same as previous - select from another page) on the page1 and how can I navigate to the specific UserControl

If you want the `UserControl`(your page 1) and the `Grid`(your page 2) must separate in two pages, for example, you want it must show a navigation effects, you may consider serializing all the data to Json string and passing it with [`OnNavigatedTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Page_OnNavigatedTo_Windows_UI_Xaml_Navigation_NavigationEventArgs_). For example, you may make all the text data as [`JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonobject), and give a identification for the `UserControl` as one of the JsonObjects, and passing to the second page, and when data come back, also send back the identification of the `UserControl`, you will know which `UserControl` will receive the data.

For serializing Json data you may reference [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Json). For passing data between pages please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigate-between-two-pages#3-pass-information-between-pages).

> What is the best solution to this?

Actually for your scenario, I think [`ContentDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog) is more filter for you. Scenario can be this, you have a `UserControl` in current page, and click the button inside the `UserControl`, a `ContentDialog` pop up, and a `Grid` located inside it, after you doing some operations, click one button inside the `ContentDialog` to close the dialog and get the return data. Now it is easy for the `UserControl` to deal with the return data. Check the [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics/cs/AppUIBasics/ControlPages/ContentDialogPage.xaml) for more details.